# How can I delete PS3 trophies?

Tags: ps3, achievements

The demo for Super Stardust HD added its trophy list to my PS3.  I don't plan on buying that game and don't want to see its list of trophies for the rest of my life.  Any way to delete them?

**Update:** you can vote for this feature on the [Playstation.Blog Share site](http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ideas/2010/03/17/deleting-trophies-with-0/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to delete trophies as soon as they have been uploaded to the Playstation Network (e.g. If you are always online, it happens as you get them.)

However, if you are not connected to the internet, there is one **DRASTIC** option, that also **WILL DELETE ALL SAVEGAMES** and all non-synched trophies, and that is to format your internal harddrive.

But, other than that, there is no way to delete a trophy one it hit PSN

Comment: They don't upload as you get them.  You have to do a sync AFAIK for them to upload.

Comment: @Corv1nus it maybe the case then when you wrote your comment, this was true, but now syncing occurs automatically. I've never had to sync and I can see all my trophies via my PSN trophy page.

Comment: @SSHThis In 2010 it was correct.  Now (2013) they sync online as soon as you view them on the PS3 unless you specify for them not to.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this as well for demos on PS3, specifically PSN games.  If you don't have it synced yet then yeah, they can be deleted.  If you've already synced by either viewing your profile or your trophies then I don't think you can delete them.

I wish you could though as I've seen the same thing for games I don't plan on buying.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible from PS4 or PS5, but only if you've earned 0 trophies in the game.

From the trophies menu, navigate to the game, press Options, and select "Delete".

[image: Screenshot of a 0% trophy list about to be deleted from the PS4 UI]

(image source: https://www.pushsquare.com/news/2015/03/guide_how_to_remove_0_percent_trophies_from_your_ps4_profile)

Answer (score -2):

You could try deleting the game from your PS3.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. =/

Comment: Worked for me, so I don't know why it won't work for you.

Comment: Well, it might work if you haven't synced it to PSN yet.

Comment: yes that might be right, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: So what does happens if I deleted the game from one console and after some time I install it again? Does all work have to be done again? It would be joke...