# How do I delete a game from my Xbox Live history?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

A comment on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/how-can-i-delete-ps3-trophies) says you can delete a game from your history if you have no achievements for it.

I remember awhile back this was not possible, and many users did not like it because playing a trial version of an arcade game would permanently add it to the game history with no way to remove it. Has this changed since the NXE update? How would I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A forum post on how to do it: http://www.gamespot.com/pages/forums/show_msgs.php?topic_id=26680459

That's how it used to be done.

Comment: Thanks! I just ran into the need for this last night and couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Good question, good answer. Just one addendum for anyone else landing on this page - you can only remove games you haven't unlocked any achievements in yet.

Comment: The video's dead.